# Javascript Code for pick random number game not working

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm new at coding, just started learning javascript and I wanted to try and write a simple game to test out my skills. I apparently have very few because the code for a basic game doesn't work.

In this game, the user is prompted to generate a random number by clicking a button, once they click the button, they can enter their guess and submit. Once they submit their guess, they can click the last button to see if their guess was correct.

Unfortunately, when I try to run the code, it skips over the if else statement, no matter what I plug in and I can't figure out why. I would much appreciate the help. Please don't just give me a better code, I know there are a ton of easier ways I could have written it. But being able to spot and sort out bugs on a simple program like this would probably help me with spotting bugs in my own code in the future.

Thanks!!!

This is the code....don't make fun of me, I'm new to this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <body>

<button onclick="genNum()"> Random Number </button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<form id="form1">
 Guess: <input name="userGuess" type="number" size="20">
</form>

<button onclick="outputnum()"> Submit </button> 

<button onclick="guessNum()"> Run Guess Num Function </button>

</body>
```

```
 var ranNum;

function genNum() {
    var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    ranNum;
}

function outputnum() {
x = document.getElementById("form1");
userguess = x.elements["userGuess"].value;
}


function guessNum() {
    if (ranNum == userguess) {
        alert("You are 70"); 
    } else if (ranNum < userguess) {
        alert("Less than 70");
    } else {
        alert("More than 70");
    }
}




 </script>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not debugging but you may do it this way : http://jsfiddle.net/n0kgj3cr/6/

Comment: Don't forget to pick an answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable with `var ranNum`, this makes it local to the function containing the declaration. So `genNum` is assigning to a local variable, while `guessNum` is looking at the global variable.

Remove the `var` keyword from the assignment in `genNum`.

Answer (score 0):

### The Quick of It

Welcome to Stack Overflow Duckling70. And, furthermore, welcome to JavaScript!

Please see a working example of your code here at [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamback42/x2frrus3/9/).

### Short Lesson in Scope

JavaScript variable declaration is interesting because it is dynamic and hoisted. Let me show you an example to show how function 'closure' and scope interplay:

```
var num = 3;

function printThree() {
    return num
}

printThree() // returns 3 bc it can access the num variable set on "global scope" 
console.log(num) // returns 3 from global scope

function printFive() {
    var num = 5; // this variable exists only within this function
    return num;
}

printFive() // returns 5 because it references num from the scope of the function
console.log(num) // returns 3 because it does not have access to the scope within the function
```

### Full HTML Solution

Lastly here is the summative solution code for your problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Steps</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Click Random Number.</li>
    <li>Enter your guess then click Submit.</li>
    <li>Click Run Guess Num Function to see how close you got!</li>
  </ol>
  <button onclick="genNum()">Random Number</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <form id="form1">
     Guess:<input name="userGuess" type="number" size="20">
  </form>
  <button onclick="setOutputNum()">Submit</button>
  <button onclick="compareGuessToNum()">Run Guess Num Function</button>
</body>
<script>
  var ranNum;
  var userGuess;

  function genNum() {
      ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ranNum;
  }

  function setOutputNum() {
      var x = document.getElementById("form1");
      userGuess = x.elements["userGuess"].value;
      // Set userGuess to number instead of string
      userGuess = +userGuess
  }

  function compareGuessToNum() {
      if (ranNum === userGuess) {
          alert("You are 70");
      } else if (ranNum < userGuess) {
          alert("Less than 70");
      } else {
          alert("More than 70");
      }
  }
</script>
</html>
```

### Further Reading

[Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#p_N7xZ5k5OET) has a good explanation on scope.